# Can I use multiple "actual" and "predicted" outputs in a single loss functions?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I am using a multiple output model in tensorflow 2.0

```
input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(INP_MAX_LENGTH), name="input")
embed_layer = layers.Embedding(EMBED_INP_DIM, embedding_size, name="embeddings", weights=[embedding_matrix],  trainable=False, input_length=INP_MAX_LENGTH)(input_layer)
  
lstm_layer1 = layers.LSTM(1024, name="lstm1")(embed_layer)
lstm_layer2 = layers.LSTM(1024, name="lstm2")(embed_layer)
  
output_layer1 = layers.Dense(1, name="output1", activation='relu')(lstm_layer1)
output_layer2 = layers.Dense(1, name="output2", activation='relu')(lstm_layer2)

concat_layer = layers.Concatenate()([output_layer1, output_layer2])

output_layer3 = layers.Dense(1, name="output3", activation='relu')(concat_layer)

model = Model(input=input_layer, output=[output_layer1, output_layer2, output_layer3])

model.compile((optimizer='adagrad', loss={'output1': loss1, 'output2': loss1, 'output3':loss2})
```

I'm using quantile loss function as my loss1 and it is working fine.

I want my loss2 function to behave something like this

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def loss2(y_true, y_pred):
   # y_true1 = y from output1
   # y_true2 = y from output2
   # y_pred1 = y from output_layer1
   # y_pred2 = y from output_layer2
   # loss = K.mean(y_true - (K.sqrt(K.square(y_true2 - y_pred2) + K.square(y_true1 - y_pred1)))), axis=-1)
   return loss
```

In short, I'm trying to implement the distance formula as my loss function and minimize the distance between two points to 0.

Can I pass y_true and y_pred from output1 and output2 to loss2 function? I tried using Concatenate to at least pass the y_preds but somehow its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you have multiple output nodes you can have loss functions that take in multiple predictions.

The basic idea is to always treat your output as a vector so when you pass it from your generator function it should be a list and when it is passed to the loss functions it should remain a list.

Rather than having different loss functions for each output node you should ideally have one loss function for all the outputs combined.